# Modeling constrained tree data structures in F#

Tags: f#, tree, modeling

As a beginning F# programmer, I've read articles like [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233226.aspx) that describe how to model simple tree data structures in F#.

I'd like to model more complex tree data structures. Consider a tree that consists of a single root that has a number of child nodes (primary nodes), each of which has a number of nodes (secondary nodes).

Let's say there are three flavors of trees, which are based on the kind of root (notice I say "kind" rather than "type" - I'm not trying to assume any model yet.)

- Roots of kind r1 can have primary nodes of kind p1 and secondary nodes of kind s1.
- Roots of kind r2 can have primary nodes of kind p2 and secondary nodes of kind s2.
- Roots of kind r3 can have primary nodes of kind p3 and secondary nodes of kind s3.

What is a good way to model this in F#? (Note: this is the start of a more complex data structure, where nodes can have attributes, and of course there will be operations that traverse trees, but I'll save that for a future question. However, as an example, all root nodes might have a Name, primary nodes an address, and secondary nodes a phone number.  if you have thoughts on this as well, do mention.)

Comment: Are primary or secondary nodes optional?

Comment: A root or node can have zero or more nodes (of the correct kind.)

Answer (score 2):

This is the type I doodled:

```
type Node<'v, 'c> = 
    {
        Value: 'v
        Children: 'c list
    }
```

or as a single case discriminated union if you prefer that:

```
type Node<'v, 'c> = N of 'v * 'c list
```

Which you can later use like this to model the first tree flavor you have:

```
type R1 = obj
type P1 = obj
type S1 = obj

type Tree1 = Node<R1, Node<P1, S1>>
```

I'm assuming here that your `R1`, `P1`, `S1` types are actually data that you want the nodes to carry.

This way max depth of the tree and types of the nodes are reflected in the type signature. Arguably you won't be able to have arbitrarily deep trees that way (or even deeper than few levels), since the type of the tree would quickly grow unwieldy ;) If you only care about depth-3 trees, that's not a concern.

Comment: Thanks. So a function that can visit any type of tree has parameter signature Node<'r, Node<'p, 's>>, correct?

Comment: Any type of depth-3 tree, yes - something closer to `Node<'a, Node<'b, 'c>> -> 'd`. I don't think you'd be able to write 'very' generic functions against such a tree though.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on the "future question" part? What if, for example, all root nodes had a Name, primary nodes had an address, and secondary nodes had a phone number. Would your model help work with such trees in all their flavors?

Comment: I'd say that's all that it's good for - those `R1` etc. types can be arbitrary records that you can expand with arbitrary properties. The `Node` type is what gives the tree its shape, the types you instantiate it with don't know anything about trees, it can be any kind of data you want (including for example an `Address` type you already have in your system).